# When to use "pointer to function" and "function pointer"?

Tags: c++

What is "pointer to function"? And what is "function pointer"?

I have not been able to find out what the difference between them really is.

What is `pFunc` in the code below called?

```
int(*pFunc)(int, int) = Add;
int i = pfunc(5,3);
....
int Add(int x, int y) { return x+y;}
```

Comment: They are the same thing...

Comment: The same difference as between "six" and "half a dozen" - no difference at all.

Comment: It's just different ways of saying the same thing. Like "pointer to int" and "int pointer".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pointer to function and function Pointer are used synonymously.